# Which Pokemon have the highest CP after evolution?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go, what are the Pokemon with the highest CP after vales (after evolving and spending stardust)

The highest I've found so far are Eevee evolutions. Is there anything better than that?

Comment: They vary wildly, but really whatever you can find the most of because you can get more candies and level that type faster.

Comment: You guys downvoted me, but I'd like to note that I eventually found a clear answer to this question.  This spreadsheet has a list of pokemon CP/Powerup (on the "Base Stats" tab): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZ1daunztOgvOZxO7ABfJPF41-2mqMDzY1Qs_0OWwq8/htmlview?sle=true#  The highest CP pokemon known, in order, are: Dragonite, Snorlax, Lapras, Exeggutor, Arcanine, Vaporeon, Gyarados, Muk, Flareon.  Silph Road also has some interesting analysis of pokemon max levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4se870/pokemon_cp_tier_list/) gives the average CP-per-powerup numbers for each pokemon type.  Each pokemon can have the same number of powerups (roughly equal to twice your trainer level), so a pokemon's max CP is proportional to its CP per powerup.

The pokemon with the best CP per powerup are Mewtwo (56), Dragonite (47), Mew (44), Moltres (44), Snorlax (42), Zapdos (42), Arcanine (40), Articuno (40), Exeggutor (40), Lapras (40), and Vaporeon (38).

However you should know there are also some comparisons such as [this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vj1nsbsIE7FVPFWE-ZRFNgoszfgfDJ1MiT81d8XbPug/htmlview?sle=true#gid=455400690)
which ignore CP and derive pokemon combat power from the base stats.  This seems to lead to the conclusion that Vaporeon is the best available pokemon.

What seems to have happened is that pokemon attack speed numbers are not getting properly reflected in pokemon go.  So pokemon with very high attack speed numbers (lightning pokemon?) are nerfed in pokemon go, while pokemon with very low attack speed numbers (water pokemon) are buffed.

This may change with time.

Answer (score -1):

Lapras have the highest CP after evaluation in pokemon on go. CP of each Pokemon matters a lot in battles.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is wrong. Have you got a source?

Comment: There's no evolution available for Lapras so this answer is wrong. See http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lapras_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Evolution